# What is the source and meaning of this Ibn Taymiyyah quote used by ISIS/Daesh?

Tags: source-identification, extremism, ibn-taymiyyah

I came across a video<sup>[1]</sup> of the burning of a Jordanian pilot by ISIS, and at the end of it, it quotes the statement:

" فإن كان في التمثيل الشائع لهم دعاء إلى الإيمان وحرز لهم عن العدوان؛ فإنه هنا من إقامة الحدود والجهاد المشروع "

attributed to Imam Ibn Taymiyyah, as if to validate their actions.

(I note that other [sources](https://www.almarjie-paris.com/2291) indicate that 'الشائع' there, is a substitute for an original word 'السائغ')

Might anyone be able to further elaborate on the phrase above: its source(s) and  meaning(s)?

---

Note:

1. [Link to reddit post containing the NSFW vid](https://www.reddit.com/r/MorbidReality/comments/2uoxx0/full_uncut_propaganda_video_of_jordanian_pilot/). Shared here in case anyone needs to verify the existence of the quoted statement.

Answer (score -1):

Found in
[Self-Organized Islam: The Islamic State In Iraq, the Levant and Ibn Taymiyyah, by Yahya M. Mesho, Hartford College - USA.
Translation: Mounir Al-Saeedani](https://caus.org.lb/product/6530/?attachment_id=10831&download_file=5b9605c8f725f)
in an Arabic translation of an English original.

> From the publications related to Ibn Taymiyyah on this sentence - the
> witness and determine its source in my compilation For the Timite
> texts, which are:
>
> **The Grand Fatwas (Ibn Taymiyyah, 1408 AH / 1987 CE: Vol. 5, p. 540)**
>
> **Al-Mustadrak on Majmoo 'Fatwas (Ibn Taymiyyah, 1418 AH / 1997 CE: CJ 3, pp. 222-224)**